# Handle 'underlying provider failed on open' in one place

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, entity-framework-6, code-reuse

I have an MVC Razor application that uses entity framework 6.0. However, if the DB is down or something, my code starts throwing exceptions at all kinds of random places like when I start evaluating my `IEnumerable<T>`s and `IQueryable<T>`s.

The model constructor is generated code that will be overwritten if I modify it which wouldn't help anyway because the constructor doesn't throw exceptions. Instead, the exceptions come in places like this

```
using (var dataContext = new ArchiveVMADDatabase.ArchiveDatabaseModel())
{
    IQueryable<HDeploy> deploys = Helpers.GetProdDeploysFromArchive(dataContext);

    var query = getBranchSelectListQuery(deploys);
    listItems.AddRange(query);// EXCEPTION IF DB IS DOWN
}
```

Is there a good way for me to handle this in one place and avoid wrapping nearly 100% of my code in giant try catch blocks? I would really like to have it just return empty sets if it can't talk to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are working with MVC or Web API, but in Web API one would use [Exception Filters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling) to centralize exception handling.

An exception filter is basically a derivative of the [`ExceptionFilterAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.exceptionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) that can create a specific response depending on the caught exception:

```
public class NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to add `try {} catch {}` blocks anywhere -- Web API triggers the configured exception filters automatically as soon as an exception reaches the outer most layer of your system (i.e. the controller level).

You can activate an exception filter only for specific `ApiController`s or globally for every controller.